# gwt change theme compiled

Tags: java, gwt, themes

Our project is pure GWT without any frameworks.  This app has been used initially by a couple of customers and the team maintained different source branches for those customers.
Now the customer base is extending and the application is distributed through partners. A challenge is they want customizing the app themes like changing logos, colors, fonts, etc
The app is not open source and we are shipping it as a binary ear archive.

What is the best way to allow such customization of GWT app? I see an option to move the images/css to a separate theme war, make a root url of that war configurable in the main application, and reference the images and css in the theme war from the main app relatively to that configurable root.
If partners want to customize theme they will create a separate theme war, overwrite the default images and css, deploy it, and change the theme war root url in the main app.

That will work but I understand it's not the best GWT practice

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is the appearance pattern. Take a look at the sencha blog:

[Sencha blog about the appearance pattern](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-gwt-3-appearance-design)

The blog describes the step how to create a appearance. Also it is not related to GXT.